# Inverse relationship between salinity and conductivity?

Tags: electrical-resistance, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

- I have a salt solution that is saturated at 40C, I measured conductivity and got 440 ms/cm.
- I then increased the temp to 50C, add more salt until the solution is saturated again, and measure conductivity again. In theory, electrical conductivity should increase with increased salt concentration, but the trend I get is as follows:

| Temp (C) | EC (ms/cm) |
| --- | --- |
| 40 | 440 |
| 50 | 423 |
| 60 | 409 |
| 70 | 393 |

The more salt I have in it that dissolves in the water, the lower the conductivity becomes, quite linearly as well.

The salt solution is about ammonium chloride, but it is not a completely pure solution, there may be some acetic acid, some heavy metals and the like in small amounts.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: "quite linearly as well" is the only part I can answer. It's linear because 40-70C is a "small" change in temperature. Better to think of it as 333-363K (less than a 10% change of $T$!). Any function of temperature $f(T)$ can be approximated with a line as long as the range of $T$ considered is sufficiently small.

Comment: I was all prepared to say "well obviously you aren't just changing the salinity, but also the temperature... so probably temperature lowers the conductivity and salinity raises it, but temperature wins." But a quick google reveals that at least for the four solutions considered here, conductivity also rises with temperature. https://www.fondriest.com/environmental-measurements/parameters/water-quality/conductivity-salinity-tds/

Comment: @AXensen I totally agree, the issue is that the conductivity is only interesting in the temperature span between 40 and 70C. It is important in a evaporation process, and the temperature can only go between 40 and 70C.

Comment: @AXensen yes, I have been looking at the effect of temperature on EC and you are correct. The EC measurements in this case have also been automatically compensated for temperature in the EC-meter I used, so should not be an issue.

Comment: Not saying you're doing anything _wrong_ by measuring between 40 and 70C, I'm just saying the only relationship you can expect to see in that range is a linear one. For your second comment, I'm suspicious of the "automatically compensated for temperature." I would say... just measure the conductivity, and if the conductivity depends on temperature I'd like to see the conductivity on my meter go up when I raise T. But you make it sound like this meter has some mechanism to remove the effect of T? Or do you just mean it removes the effect of T on the electronics used to measure the conductivity.

Comment: Its a standard in most EC-meters: https://www.vernier.com/til/2959

Comment: Is your meter, like the one described in this link, only meant to do this accurately between 5 and 35C? Also that the meter described here does a correction that's meant to be accurate for water that just has a bit of salt - like lakes and rivers, but you're measuring a saturated solution. So maybe the conductivity is going up as we'd expect, but the meter does some weird overcorrection that eliminates the effect. Does the meter have a "just tell me the damn conductivity and don't do any mysterious adjustments to it" setting? That might be useful.

Comment: Also occurred to me... is solid salt building up on your meter blocking it up and increasing the measured resistance?

Answer (score 2):

You are changing two things simultaneously, which makes it hard to reach simple conclusions. According to [this paper (DOI:10.1039/C9CP06479F)](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2020/cp/c9cp06479f), which studies the effect of temperature and concentration, temperature increases conductivity but concentration is more complicated: at low concentrations conductivity increases but goes through a maximum and the decreases at high concentrations. In your case you are changing both variables and it is not clear how you are moving on this graph. There is a lot of research on this subject, you should be able to find more information.

[image: conductivity as a function of temperature and concentration]

Answer (score 0):

Solution conductivity depends on three things: carrier concentration, carrier mobility, and carrier charge. As you saturate the solution, you are also decreasing carrier mobility which may dominate depending on the type of salt.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 major effects contributing to decrease of conductivity at high concentrations:

- Each ion repulses ions with the same charge sign and attracts those with the opposite charge sign. The leads to the state each ion is surrounded of the thought cloud of [molecular entities](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/M03986) with the nonzero opposite net charge. When the potential difference is applied on a solution, this cloud creates the reactive intensity of electrostatic field of the opposite to the external one, decreasing its net value, leading to lower effective ion mobility, ion molar conductivity and solution conductivity.
- Concentrated solutions often tend to form hydrated [ionic pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_association) that have decreased or zero net charge, leading to the same effects.
- Concentrated solutions modify properties and behavior of water as the solvent, from viscosity to permittivity, that is effectively often leading to the same effects as above.